# How currentuser send request notification to another user via fcm in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a list of users those data in available in my firestore.
I want that, if currentuser want to send a request notification to other use. How I build it?

Comment: can you share your current sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Alright.

A user can have multiple FCM tokens because tokens are binded to a device and they have no clue about User entity.

So what you can do is to create a **tokens** array inside each user document and when a user authorize to receive notification on his device, you add the new token to that array.

You could write a cloud function called notifyUser where you pass in the userSender ID and the userRecipient ID. And then you could simply grab the userRecipient user object and then call the messaging() function from the admin SDK to send your payload to all devices (based on the user token).